# How to check if parent variables

Tags: theming

My login form generated by `theme_form()` contains a password field, which is generated by `theme_password()`.

My goal is to add certain variable into $variables of `theme_password()`. But ONLY in case, when parent's form NID == 5.

Comment: If this is on a node page, where the URL is node/%nid regardless of what the path is, you can use `arg(1)` to get the NID.

Comment: This solution is working but however it is very limited. Please lets focus on just template.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your theme's **template.php** to add a [`theme_password()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_password/7) wrapper to inject your custom vars:

```
function MYTHEME_password(&$variables) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if(isset($node->nid) && $node->nid == 5) { //Check for display on node/5
    //@TODO: Add $variables altercation
  }
  return theme_password($variables);
}
```